# Maximization under constraints - can't find algebraic/closed form solution even though know it exists

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I want to solve the following Constrained optimization program:

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
     \max_{\{F\}} F \cdot P\left(v \geq -\alpha \cdot \ln\left(1-\frac{F}{\alpha}\right)\right)\\
     \text{Subject to: } F>0, F<\alpha
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

Where $\alpha$ is a (real) parameter strictly greater than $0$, i.e $\alpha \in {R}^*$, and where $v$ follows a (continuous) Uniform distribution over (0,1).

**I wish to find a closed form solution for $F$, as a function of $\alpha$.**

---

---

Here is **what I have done so far**:

- The above program is equivalent to:
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
       \max_{\{F\}} F \cdot \left[1-P\left(v \leq -\alpha \cdot \ln\left(1-\frac{F}{\alpha}\right)\right)\right] \\
       \text{Subject to: } F>0, F<\alpha\\
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}
- Then, we know:
  $$P\left(v \leq -\alpha \cdot \ln\left(1-\frac{F}{\alpha}\right)\right) =
  \begin{cases}
      0 &\text{ If} -\alpha \cdot \ln(1-\frac{F}{\alpha}) < 0,\\
      -\alpha \cdot \ln(1-\frac{F}{\alpha}) &\text{ If} -\alpha \cdot \ln(1-\frac{F}{\alpha}) \in [0,1],\\
      1 &\text{ If} -\alpha \cdot \ln(1-\frac{F}{\alpha}) > 1
  \end{cases}
  $$
- But:
  (a) Having $F>0$ (one of the constraint), ensures that $-\alpha \cdot \ln(1-\frac{F}{\alpha}) > 0$, since $\alpha > 0$. Hence the first region of the CDF (when $<0$) can be ignored. And, (b) We see clearly that $F$ such that $-\alpha \cdot ln(1-\frac{F}{\alpha}) > 1$ is never optimal, as the objective function would be equal to zero in that case: $ F \cdot \bigg[1- 1 \bigg] = 0$
- Hence, the previous program is in turn equivalent to:
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
       \max_{\{F\}} F \cdot \bigg[1- \big( -\alpha \cdot \ln(1-\frac{F}{\alpha})  \big) \bigg] = \underbrace{F \cdot \bigg[1+\alpha \cdot \ln(1-\frac{F}{\alpha}) \bigg]}_{\stackrel{def}{=}f(F)}  \\
       \text{Subject to: } F>0, F<\alpha, F \leq \alpha (1-e^{-1/\alpha})\\
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}
  Where the added third condition ensures that  $-\alpha \cdot \ln(1-\frac{F}{\alpha}) \in (0,1]$
- The first order condition is:
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
  \frac{\partial f(F)}{\partial F}: 1 + \alpha \cdot \ln\left(1-\frac{F}{\alpha}\right) - \frac{\alpha F}{\alpha - F} \stackrel{!}{=} 0
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}
  Which I don't know how to factorise, and hence solve for F.
- I am pretty sure a (unique?) solution exist to problem, as I have plotted the function (and solved it numerically with Mathematica).
- Nota Bene: If needed, some restriction on the upper bound of $\alpha$ can be made.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

The first order condition is equivalent to

$$1=\exp\bigg[\frac{F(1+\frac{1}{\alpha})-1}{\alpha-F}\bigg]+\frac{F}{\alpha} \quad \quad (1)$$

The function on the RHS takes the values $e^{-1}$ and $1+\frac{1}{\alpha+1}$ at $F=0$ and $F=\frac{1}{1+1/\alpha}$ respectively, and is continuous on $[0,1+\frac{1}{\alpha+1}]$. Therefore, by the intermediate value theorem, there exists $F^*\in(0,\alpha)$ satisfying $(1)$. Since the RHS is strictly increasing on $(0,\alpha)$, there can be only one such $F^*$.

The second derivative of $f(F)$ is

$$\frac{-1}{(1-F/\alpha)}+\frac{-1}{(1-F/\alpha)^2}<0$$

which shows that $f$ is strictly concave on $(0,\alpha)$. Therefore $F^*$ is indeed the unique global maximum.

From the inequality $e^x\geq 1+x$, and the fact that $F^*<\frac{1}{1+1/\alpha}$, we see that $F^*< \alpha (1-e^{-1/\alpha})$. Hence at the optimum the objective function is strictly positive.